# T-SQL Select between two ranges and in a list

Tags: range, between

I know this has to be an easy one, but I have been searching and cannot locate why my logic is wrong.

I have a select statement like below.

```
SELECT * from MyTable where Column1 between 1 and 5 or Column1 between 10 
and 15 or Column2 in (1,2,3)
```

So I need values based on two ranges in Column1 and a list in Column2.

It is returning the correct rows for my ranges, but I am getting extra values based on my list. I know it has to be my AND/ OR but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you show us sample data along with desired output?

Comment: `AND Column2 IN (1,2,3)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess sample data and desired results would have been good information. I ended up finding my own answer through trial and error. Thank you for looking. I needed to use my and operator in each of my ranges.

SELECT * from MyTable where Column1 between 1 and 5 and Column2 in (1,2,3) 
or Column1 between 10 and 15 and Column2 in (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from MyTable where (Column1 between 1 and 5) or (Column1 between 10 
and 15) or Column2 in (1,2,3)